# How fast is the response time of a battery for a particular current demand?

Tags: batteries, current-source

If you demand a particular amperage, can the battery provide that amperage instantaneously or will it need some time to build up to that level?

I guess it will need time, but would like some references/thoughs.

Comment: How much current? What kind of battery? Or do you want some general information?

Comment: Li-ion battery. And well the current is within the nominal discharge rate. I just need some general info, I know that which a change in chemistry and stack the limits will change, but i am interested in just a qualitative view for now.

Answer (score 4):

The main limiting factor will be the *inductance* of the battery and its leads. [Here's a discussion](http://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?t=952523) by someone who claims this is can a problem when using long leads in RC motor systems. In general inductance limits the rate of change of current flow in an electrical system.

The usual design approach is to put decoupling capacitors near the load. This also reduces noise interference in sensitive parts of the system or nearby electronics.

Note that "instantaneously" is a *really short time*; this isn't a problem for most systems.

Comment: Hmm, so it depends on the circuit? The battery itself can provide current as soon as demanded? If I have a battery model (mathematical) and I apply a step current demand input to it, it will tract the step without any transient time?

Comment: That depends on the model, whether it's detailed enough to cover internal inductance. What's your actual requirement - microseconds, nanoseconds, picoseconds? Li-ion batteries can certainly handle the few microseconds turn-on time requirement for GSM transmitters, for example.

Comment: Thanks! The model i have made is detailed enough for the internal inductances, however I wanted to verify if it performs realistically. I plan to use it in parallel to an renewable power source. If there is a step demand of current I want to see the response of the system. I know the dynamic response of the renewable power source, but i am not sure about the battery. It will provide power faster than the renewable source, but how fast can it be?

Comment: The point I've been making obliquely is that it's quite hard to have a *really* sudden current demand; for practical purposes the inductance of the wiring will be the limiting factor.

Comment: @pjc50 - spot on (extra point). Making a step current with zero rise time is theoretically possible but... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function  The speed of current in a conductor is limited by the propagation of the electromagnetic wave. Hence inductive and capacitive effects will alter its transmission speed. Unless you have a very good stopwatch it won't be easy to measure because its a really really small time.

Answer (score 3):

The time response of a battery can be seen in 'EIS' (Electrochemical Impedance Spectroscopy) plots. In '[Electrochemical Impedance Spectroscopy of a LiFePo4 Half cell](http://www.comsol.com/papers/13446/download/cugnet_paper.pdf%E2%80%8E)' they went out to 200Khz, and see only the double layer capacitance. There is no evidence of a delay.

At low frequencies (milli-Hz), you start to see things change. For instance, if you apply a sudden step change in current to the battery, the resulting voltage step will be just as fast as the current step, but will then sort of sag, and transition into what you would expect for charging (or discharging) at that current.

There is a detailed equivalent circuit on page 192 of [Diagnosis_of_electrochemical_impedance_spectroscopy_in_lithium_ion_batteries](http://cdn.intechopen.com/pdfs/29293/InTech-Diagnosis_of_electrochemical_impedance_spectroscopy_in_lithium_ion_batteries.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following references in regard to the response time of battery technologies.

[1.] http://www.iec.ch/whitepaper/pdf/iecWP-energystorage-LR-en.pdf

[2.] X. Luo, J. Wang, M. Dooner, and Jonathan Clarke, ''Overview of current development in electrical energy storage technologies and the application potential in power system operation,'' *Appl. Energy*, vol. 137, pp. 511-536, 2015.

Comment: The first link now just redirects to the main page for https://www.iec.ch/ - what were that paper's title & authors?