# What is the ramp rate of a battery used on the grid?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, power-engineering, storage, frequency-response

For grid applications, I am looking for typical ramp rate of Li-ion batteries.  I am specifically interested in batteries used for frequency management.  So suppose I have a 1MW grid connected battery and the grid sees a disturbance in which there is loss of generation.  What kinds of maximum ramp rate can I expect from Li-ion battery in say one second?  Is it 30% of rated capacity per second?

Are there metrics like 0 to 99% rated capacity in N seconds?  What are typical values of N for Li-ion?

Comment: I'd assume it can ramp within one cycle once the decision has been made as there are no moving parts, but as usual you need to check with the manufacturer..

Comment: The chemistry of the battery will not allow an instant ramp rate.
I am also interested in any industry standards for ramp rate of energy storage units that are used for primary frequency response.

Comment: It's going to be all about the inverter and its control electronics, the battery chemistry is irrelevant. For exanple, Lithium will be at least as good as lead acid. LA delivers full power when you turn the key in your car, in a millisecond.

Comment: The last guy the drop a wrench across 1MWh of lithium cells can attest to their ramp rate. The control electronics can be tuned well and likely react within a cycle or two.

Comment: Have you looked around for a manufacturer's technical sales brochure or datasheet? I'd suggest starting with the ABB website.

Answer (score 1):

The reference suggests that the response time of most of the battery technologies is less than one second. Therefore, for grid applications, maximum physical ramp-rate can be executed by the battery storage devices will be driven by ratings of PE-converters and will be independent of the battery technology selected.

Ref.: [How fast is the response time of a battery for a particular current demand?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/70651/how-fast-is-the-response-time-of-a-battery-for-a-particular-current-demand/282911#282911)